# How to check if my program is running on MinGW(or MSYS) shell, or on CMD?

Tags: mingw, msys2, msys

I use MinGW or MSYS to develop my program, I want to make my program behave slightly differently when running on MinGW(or MSYS) shell than what it does when running on CMD.

This requires the run-time ability to check if my program is running on MinGW(or MSYS) shell, I would like to know if there is any way to do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the MSYSTEM environment variable is set. If it is you are running under MSYS/MinGW.

Comment: The MSYSTEM environment variable won't be set if directly calling MSYS binaries (instead of using msys2.exe / msys2-shell.cmd). Checking kernel might be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

If you directly call MSYS binaries from Windows (instead of using msys2.exe / msys2-shell.cmd), the MSYSTEM environment variable won't be set.

So, checking kernel information will be more reliable:

```
if [[ "$(uname -s)" =~ ^MSYS_NT.* ]]; then
    echo "In MSYS"
else
    echo "Not in MSYS"
fi
```